# Difficulty With Forecasting Using Weekly Data With fbprophet

Tags: facebook-prophet

I have a CSV with time-series datapoints at 10-minute intervals for the entire month of November that I am looking to train a FB Prophet model with. The data is *very* seasonal, on a weekly basis, and Saturday and Sunday consistently have lower values than their weekday counterparts. This is what the data (always non-negative) looks like with the `fbprophet` `y_hat` values:

[image: Original data]

This is what I am doing to get the model:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./input.csv');

m = Prophet(weekly_seasonality=False)
m.add_seasonality('weekly', period=7, fourier_order=3)
m.fit(df)

future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=10)

forecast = m.predict(future)

fig = m.plot(forecast).savefig('out.png')
```

However, the 10-period forecast that is generated looks terrible, especially considered there are negative values in the training data:
[image: 10-period forecast]

I have tried adjusting the `period=` and `fourier_order=` values, as well as various `changepoint_prior_scale=` values, but the forecasts are nowhere near the training data.

With `Prophet(changepoint_prior_scale=0.50)`:

[image: changepoint_prior_scape=0.50]

With `m.add_seasonality('weekly', period=5, fourier_order=5)`:

[image: m.add_seasonality('weekly', period=5, fourier_order=5)]

What should I begin to try next in order to get predictions that are not wildly different than the trained data? I believe that the issue is based in the fact that I have a 10-minute interval for my data points. So, when I try to increase the period to the number of 10-minute periods in a 7-day week (1,008), I get the following:

[image: period=1008]

I am looking for more information related to how I can use Prophet to more-accurately forecast this data, but I believe I am missing some information when it comes to how to train the model. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm having similar issues.  Following this...

Comment: @doctorV I used `m = Prophet(growth='logistic', changepoint_prior_scale=16.99)` and `future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=2050, freq='10min')` and got a very good-looking forecast based on my seasonal data. It would appear that the frequency and period of the data is the most-important aspect when tuning FBProphet, so I would start there.